# DISTANCE expected input to be an agent but got the agentset (agentset, 16 patches) instead

Tags: netlogo

I keep getting this error message (DISTANCE expected input to be an agent but got the agentset (agentset, 16 patches) instead.) at the bottom of my code when I run the following code:

```
globals
[
  x-grid-size ;; Global variable for inter-city grid-sizing in the x direction
  y-grid-size ;; Global variable for inter-city grid-sizing in the y-direction
  grid-x-inc ;; Global variable for inter-city street spacing in x-direction
  grid-y-inc ;; Global variable for inter-city street spacing in y-direction
  roads ;; Global variable for inter-city road network
  outer-roads ;; Global variable for outer-city road network
  a-station
]

breed [inter-buildings inter-building] ;; Inter-city buildings such as office, retail, business, apartments, etc.
breed [outer-buildings outer-building] ;; Outer-city buildings such as residential, reatail, apartments, etc.
breed [AVs AV]

AVs-own
[
  goal
  trip-status ;; (0 = heading to station, 1 = pick-up passenger from station, 2 = heading to drop-off point)
  destination ;; 
]

patches-own
[
  my-row ;; The row of the intersection counting from the upper left corner of the world.  -1 for non-intersection patches.
  my-column ;; The column of the intersection counting from the upper left corner of the world. -1 for non-intersection patches.
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-globals ;; Command for setting up and initializing the global variables
  setup-patches ;; Command for setting up the patches for the inter-city and outer-city zones of simulation

  ;;setup-building-infras ;; Command for setting up the building infrastructure on approp. patches
  if show-buildings? ;; if the show-building switch is true then building infras will be shown
  [
    create-inter-buildings Inter-City_Density ;; Creating the inter-city building density
    [
      set heading 0
      set shape "square"
      set size (random 0.5) + 1
      set color grey
      move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != white] ;; if building is on the road, move it to patch that isn't white
      setxy (-25 + random-float 50) (-25 + random-float 50) ;; Set position building infras anywhere ranging from -25 to 25 for x- and y-directions
      ask inter-buildings
      [
        if (pcolor = white) ;; if building infras. still lands on road move to patch that isn't white in color
        [
          move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != white]
        ]

        if (pcolor = red)
        [
          move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 96]
        ]

        ifelse (pcolor = white)
        [
          move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != white]
        ]

        [
          if (pcolor = 66)
          [
            move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != 66]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]

    create-outer-buildings Outer-City_Density ;; Creating the outer-city building density
    [
      set heading 0
      set shape "square"
      set size (random 0.05) + 0.65
      set color yellow
      move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != white] ;; if building is on the road, move it to patch that isn't white
      setxy (0 + random-float 0) (0 + random-float 0) ;; Set position building infras anywhere ranging from -50 to 50 for x- and y-directions

      ask outer-buildings
      [
        if (pcolor = white) ;; if building infras. still lands on road move to patch that isn't white in color
        [
          move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != white]
        ]

        if (pcolor = red)
        [
          move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 96]
        ]

        ifelse (pcolor = white)
        [
          move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != white]
        ]

        [
          if (pcolor = 66)
          [
            move-to one-of patches with [pcolor != 66]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

  create-AVs (Market_Pentr) * Vehicles 
  [
    set size 0.4
    set shape "car"
    set color orange
    move-to one-of roads
    set goal a-station 
    set-heading-to-station

  ]

  create-TVs (1 - Market_Pentr) * Vehicles
  [
    set size 0.5
    set shape "car"
    set color magenta
    move-to one-of roads
  ]
 reset-ticks
end

to set-heading-to-station
  set trip-status 0

  let goal-candidates patches with [pcolor = red and any? neighbors with [pcolor = white]]
  set a-station one-of goal-candidates

  set destination one-of goal-candidates with [self != [a-station] of myself]
end

to setup-patches ;; Command for setting up patch design for simulation
  ask patches
  [
    ifelse ((pxcor <= 25 and pxcor >= -25) and (pycor <= 25 and pycor >= -23)) ;; if a patch is between pxcor and pycor of -25 and 25
    [
      set my-row -1
      set my-column -1
      set pcolor yellow + 3 ;; set the patch's color to yellow for inter-city block representation
    ]

    [
      set pcolor 96 ;; otherwise set the patch's color to a modified sky blue for outer-city block representation
    ]
  ]

  ask patches 
  [
    if ((pxcor <= 25 and pxcor >= -25) and (pycor <= 25 and pycor >= -25))
    [
      set roads patches with
      [
        (floor ((pxcor + max-pxcor - floor (grid-x-inc - 1)) mod grid-x-inc) = 0) or
        (floor ((pycor + max-pycor) mod grid-y-inc) = 0)
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ;; setup the a-station
  set a-station patches with [(pxcor >= 36 and pxcor <= 39) and (pycor >= 37 and pycor <= 40)]
  ask a-station
  [
    set pcolor red
  ]

ask roads
  [
    ifelse ((pxcor <= 25 and pxcor >= -26) and (pycor <= 26 and pycor >= -25))
    [
      set pcolor white
    ]

    [
      set pcolor white ;; this is a placeholder
    ]
  ]
end

to Drive-Around
  ask AVs
  [
    if [pcolor] of patch-here = white
    [
      face drive-forward
      forward AV-speed
    ]
  ]
end

to-report drive-forward
  ask AVs
  [
    if goal = a-station ;;and (member? patch-here [neighbors4] of a-station) ;; CHANGE THIS SO IS CONDUCIVE WITH PEDESTRIAN AGENTS LATER ON
    [
      set trip-status 1
      set goal destination
    ]

    if goal = destination ;;and (member? patch-here [neighbors4] of destination)
    [
      set trip-status 2
      ;; this could be the count of the number of assisted citizens

      set-heading-to-station
      let A-Station_X_Cor [pxcor] of a-station
      let A-Station_Y_Cor [pycor] of a-station
      let Destination_X_Cor [pxcor] of destination
      let Destination_Y_Cor [pycor] of destination

      let required_range 1.5 * (
        abs(A-Station_X_Cor - [xcor] of myself) +
        abs(Destination_X_Cor - A-Station_X_Cor) +
        abs(A-Station_Y_Cor - [ycor] of myself) +
        abs(Destination_Y_Cor - A-Station_Y_Cor))

      if required_range < 50
      [
        set goal a-station
      ]
    ]
  ]

  let choices neighbors with [pcolor = white]
  let choice min-one-of choices [distance [goal] of myself]
  report choice
end
```

I am trying to see if I can get the vehicle agents to move to a specific location in simulation, but at the same time stay on the white patches which are the roadways in my city grid system. One thing to note is that the primitive known as `distance` keeps giving me errors and I am not sure what the error message is telling me nor do I know what to do at this point. I have tried placing an if statement in the `to Drive-Around` command but it doesn't seem to remove the error message.

Comment: Please edit your question to only show the relevant code. Probably just the procedure that is generating the error message plus a description of what the variables mean. What the error message means is that you are asking the distance to 16 agents instead of 1, but I can't tell where that is or why.

Answer (score 0):

In one place you have:

```
set a-station patches with [...]
```

which makes `a-station` hold an agentset.

In another place you have:

```
set goal a-station
```

if `a-station` was holding an agentset, now `goal` is also holding an agentset.

And then when you do:

```
distance [goal] of myself
```

that's an error, because you can't compute the distance to agentset. You can only compute the distance to an individual agent (patch or turtle).

I don't know what fix to suggest, because I don't understand enough about the intent of the code.